# ViewChild doesn’t work to me - upgrade to beta7

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

```
import {Page,NavController,NavParams,Platform,IonicApp} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabspage/tabspage.html'
})

@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs

export class TabsPage {
     tab1;
     tab2;
     tab3;

     constructor(app:IonicApp, params:NavParams) {
        this.tab1 = Page1;
        this.tab2 = Page2;
        this.tab3 = Page3;

     }


     onPageDidEnter() {
         this.tabRef.select(1);
      }

}
```

I have this code. This code is inside of a typescript file. I get the error: Error TS1146: Declaration expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `@ViewChild()` should be inside your class declaration.

```
export class TabsPage {
    @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For it says expecting declaration, I think you may need import 'Tabs' class in advance.

```
import {Tabs} from '..~~tabs';
```